# python html scraping whith BeautifulSoup separately

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrape from this html part, the 2,768 and 25,000 separately:

```
 <td class="ColCompany">Company</td>
<td class="alignCenter">2,768</td><td class="alignCenter" >
<a class="aMeasure" title="Text. href="/Reports/Index#Measure"> 69 </a></td>
<td class="alignCenter">25,000</td>
<td class="alignCenter">7</td>
```

with this python code:

```
def get_posts():
    global Comp_Name
    Comp_Name=""
    plain_text = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.findAll('td',{'class': 'alignCenter'}):

        title = link.string
        if title != None :
            list_of_titles.append(title)
```

Unfortunately, he returns the two values ​​together,

I would be happy to assist you so that each numer will be separatel

10x

Answer (score 0):

To get these two numbers, you could use this script:

```
data = ''' <td class="ColCompany">Company</td>
<td class="alignCenter">2,768</td><td class="alignCenter" >
<a class="aMeasure" title="Text. href="/Reports/Index#Measure"> 69 </a></td>
<td class="alignCenter">25,000</td>
<td class="alignCenter">7</td>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

numbers = [t.get_text(strip=True) for t in soup.select('.alignCenter')]
print(numbers[0])
print(numbers[2])
```

Prints:

```
2,768
25,000
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on html supplied you might be able to use `nth-of-type`. Though accessing twice seems less efficient than just indexing into list of both.

```
soup.select_one('td.alignCenter:nth-of-type(2)').text
```

and

```
soup.select_one('td.alignCenter:nth-of-type(3)').text
```

The `nth-of-type` indices came from testing with jsoup on your html and adding in surrounding table tags. Your mileage may vary but the principle is the same.